# Pandas groupby create new column based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

In the table below, I want to produce the column **new area** for the group created by address related fields X,Y,Z (Groupby XYZ).
If in the code column, if the value is A, just count that area only once and add the remaining area for other codes.

So for this group, the new area should be 100(A)+200(B)+300(C)= 600.
Note that can't take the sum since A is repeated twice. Just want one area for value A to be counted in the sum, not all of them

[image]

To get the above table:

````
df['X'] = ['222 North St','222 North St','222 North St','222 North St','115 John St','115 John St','115 John St']
df['Y'] = ['Seattle','Seattle','Seattle','Seattle','Chicago','Chicago','Chicago']
df['Z'] = ['WA','WA','WA','WA','IL','IL','IL']
df['code'] = ['A','B','A','C','A','A','B']
df['area'] = [100,200,100,300,200,200,50]```
````

Comment: It would help if you gave a minimum reproducible example to work with.

Comment: Isn't the table helpful?

Comment: @HP_17 is there any reason why you want to use ```groupby``` in particular. Seems like there could be better ways to do this without it.

Comment: @george.adams1 since I want to sum up area values for a particular address

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this works, but not sure if it's the most efficient way. Since you didn't specify *which* code you wanted to take when there were multiple, I assumed they would hold the same value for `area` and so dropped duplicates.

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['X'] = ['222 North St','222 North St','222 North St','222 North St','115 John St','115 John St','115 John St']
df['Y'] = ['Seattle','Seattle','Seattle','Seattle','Chicago','Chicago','Chicago']
df['Z'] = ['WA','WA','WA','WA','IL','IL','IL']
df['code'] = ['A','B','A','C','A','A','B']
df['area'] = [100,200,100,300,200,200,50]

df2 = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['X','Y','Z','code']).groupby(['X','Y','Z']).agg({'area':'sum'}).reset_index()
df = pd.merge(df,df2,how='left',on=['X','Y','Z']).rename(columns={'area_x':'area','area_y':'area sum'})
```

Also, if you were able to provide the first part of the above code yourself, you'd attract more people to try and answer your question.

EDIT:

```
# drop duplicates but only for code = A
df_A = df[df['code']=='A'].drop_duplicates(subset=['X','Y','Z','code'])

# groupby and sum now that A only appears once - this creates the 'area sum'
df2 = pd.concat([df[df['code']!='A'],df_A]).groupby(['X','Y','Z']).agg({'area':'sum'}).reset_index()

# merge onto original dataframe
df = pd.merge(df,df2,how='left',on=['X','Y','Z']).rename(columns={'area_x':'area','area_y':'area sum'})
```

Comment: Yes for the code A, area would be same everytime

Comment: But for other codes, it could be different area values. I don't want them to be removed. Let's say for B we can have area value of 100 and 150. We need to add them

Comment: So is it _only_ area A that you want to take 1 result for? And any other areas you want to sum?

Comment: Yes, the area code A is always same, whereas for other codes, it can be different.

Comment: I've added an edit to reflect your comment.

Comment: Thanks, did not understand the logic behind 2nd line!! df_A['code'] = 'A'

Comment: You're right, it's not needed. It was just an artifact of me messing about with the code. I've removed it.